# Show me some fireworks!

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, matrix, animation

**Given, in any way and order,**

- dimensions (in whichever order you want)
- a probability (in whatever format you want)
- number of iterations (you may choose whether to count the initial state or not)

**do *one* of the following:**

- animate, or
- output each step of, or
- return a list of states of

**a spaces-filled sky of those dimensions.**

**For each iteration:**

- every sky character has the given probability of becoming a `*`
- the eight characters that surround any `*` become
  `\` `|` `/`
  `-`      `-`
  `/` `|` `\`, if they don't become stars, however,
- if a character is within range of two `*`s, make it an `X`

#### Example

The 7×22 sky (frame for clarity only – don't output the frame)

```
┌──────────────────────┐
│                      │
│                      │
│                      │
│                      │
│                      │
│                      │
│                      │
└──────────────────────┘
```

could with 1% probability become

```
┌──────────────────────┐
│  *                   │
│                      │
│                      │
│                      │
│                      │
│           *          │
│                      │
└──────────────────────┘
```

and the next step

```
┌──────────────────────┐
│ - - *                │
│ /|\                  │
│          *           │
│                      │
│          \|/         │
│          - -         │
│          /|\         │
└──────────────────────┘
```

and then

```
┌──────────────────────┐
│    - -               │
│    /|\  \|/          │
│         - -          │
│         /|\          │
│                      │
│      * *             │
│                      │
└──────────────────────┘
```

and

```
┌──────────────────────┐
│                      │
│                      │
│                      │
│                      │
│     \|X|/            │
│     - X -            │
│     /|X|\          * │
└──────────────────────┘
```

and so on

```
┌──────────────────────┐
│                      │
│                      │
│                      │
│                   *  │
│                      │
│                   \|/│
│                   - -│
└──────────────────────┘
```

Comment: If someone viewing this is not familiar at all about the USA culture, they might be confused to why you are launching fireworks on 4th July.

Comment: @Okx to destroy all who oppose, of course!

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1858/)

Answer (score 5):

## ES6, <strike>520</strike> 496 bytes

Clipping and everything else should work now.

```
(w,h,p,i,r=0,s=($=>{while(++r<i)for(j=0,_=$[r]=[],z=$[r-1]||[];j<w*h;){k=j+1,l='*',c=0
n=(j%w&&z[j-1]==l&&++c)|(k%w&&z[k]==l&&++c)?'-':' '
n=(z[j-w]==l&&++c)|(z[j+w]==l&&++c)?'|':n
n=(j%w&&z[j-w-1]==l&&++c)|(k%w&&z[k+w]==l&&++c)?'\\':n
n=(k%w&&z[k-w]==l&&++c)|(j%w&&z[j+w-1]==l&&++c)?'/':n
_[j++]=Math.random()<p?l:c>1?'X':n}})(x=[])||x)=>{c=document.body.children[0],r=0;while(++r<i)setTimeout((k=0)=>{for(r++,c.innerHTML='';k<h;)c.innerHTML+=s[r].slice(k*w,++k*w).join('')+'\n'},90*r);r=0}
```

[View animation!](https://jsfiddle.net/2ndAttmt/utt4phee/2/)

Saved 24 bytes thanks to Zacharý's tip.

### Old solution, 478 bytes (with clipping bug)

I think I got all the rules correct, however the solution has a clipping problem where everything exiting right/left wraps around one line lower/higher on the opposite side.

```
(w,h,p,i,r=0,s=($=>{while(++r<i)for(j=0,_=$[r]=[],z=$[r-1]||[];j<w*h;){c=0
n=(z[j-1]=='*'&&++c)|(z[j+1]=='*'&&++c)?'-':' '
n=(z[j-w]=='*'&&++c)|(z[j+w]=='*'&&++c)?'|':n
n=(z[j-w-1]=='*'&&++c)|(z[j+w+1]=='*'&&++c)?'\\':n
n=(z[j-w+1]=='*'&&++c)|(z[j+w-1]=='*'&&++c)?'/':n
_[j++]=Math.random()<p?'*':c>1?'X':n}})(x=[])||x)=>{c=document.body.children[0],r=0;while(++r<i)setTimeout((k=0)=>{for(r++,c.innerHTML='';k<h;)c.innerHTML+=s[r].slice(k*w,++k*w).join('')+'\n'},90*r);r=0}
```

[View old.](https://jsfiddle.net/2ndAttmt/utt4phee/)

Comment: Nicely done. Can't you fix the clipping by appending blank columns on the sides, animate, and then chop?

Comment: Couldn't you define a variable to be `'*'` since you use it SO often?

Comment: @Zacharý Good tip, I will define variables for `'*'` and other commonly used things.

Comment: If only JS had macros.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 65 chars or 71 bytes*

Prompts for dimensions (rows, columns), then for iterations (not counting initial state), then for probability (as *n* in ¹⁄*ₙ*).

```apl
⎕{1=?⍺⍺:'*'⋄2≤+/b←'*'=1↓4⌽,⍵:'X'⋄⊃b/'-/|\\|/-'}⌺3 3{⍺⍺⎕←⍵}⍣⎕⊢⎕⍴''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY/BTgIxEIbv@xRza4Ksy4KGhGRjFPWkJzTRhEuBXWhSWrItEQKcNKjIEhPj0Yv6CHoh8WXmRdbp0jSd/plv/pnhI@n3plzqfo7ZhuHmvXnLWGcsZM/EjAG@PMCJ1rZ1fHFVCCJaZ/vXzctTIE5PQCvwE2UiF42dyjga8glzpdkHJDoFJbox9IQZST71PHx6PBdpnJPPLIyOMNvSbbASI/MqPn/vBR1cvpKOQly@HeD6r4zZb4PdOABX952A@cG83Z4HPlvgeluD2mxnQo5USfACsy8nVp/uzX4Yy6lrDsVxzb06VKvFfHVI9Z0pO9nVcjxUxjt0lMsJG6fcCq0or7QlYKysUH0QSljBJRjLbeyFlcqODwP62gF0B1zRxjqB0j8)

`⎕⍴''` prompt for input and use that to **r**eshape an empty string, padding with spaces as needed

`⊢` yield that

…`⍣⎕` prompt for input and apply the following function on the above (*⍵*) that many times:

…`{`…`}` derive a function using the below function as operand (*⍺⍺*), as follows:

`⎕←⍵` print the argument

`⍺⍺` apply the following function:

…`⌺3 3` apply the following function on each element's 3×3 Moore neighborhood:

`⎕{`…`}` get input and use it as operand (*⍺⍺*) to derive a new function

`?⍺⍺` random integer among the first *⍺⍺* integers

`1=` Boolean if equal to one

`:` if true:

`'*'` return a star

`⋄` else:

`,⍵` ravel (flatten) the argument (the Moore neighborhood)

`4⌽` rotate it cyclically four steps to the left

`1↓` drop one element (the original center)

`'*'=` Boolean list where equal to a star

`b←` store that as *b*

`+/` sum that

`2≤` Boolean if two or higher

`:` if true:

`'X'` return an X

`⋄` else:

`b/'-/|\\|/-'` use the *b* to to filter the string

`⊃` pick the first one, if there are none, pick the prototype (a space)

---

<sup>* To run in Dyalog Classic, simply replace `⌺` with `⎕U233A`</sup> .